# pass value for TestPlan.SERIALIZE_THREADGROUPS through jmeter commandline in non-gui mode

Tags: jmeter

In jmeter test plan I can see checkbox Run Thread groups Consecutively.

[image]

For my test scenario, I want to change the value of this option from command-line to toggle between parallel and consecutive mode while running jmeter in non-gui mode. 
I have searched in the documentation but couldn't find any information over passing this boolean value from command-line.

Is there a way to modify this parameter from commandline in jmeter non-gui mode ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not possible to do cleanly this.

A not clean option, is to do a replacement of field in xml.

Comment: That is one of the options came across when I was investigating but, as you said it is not a clean way to do it. By any chance are you aware of the reason why jmeter puts this restriction on this parameter to not be passed through command line ?